Why this x86 NASM assembly cause fault?
I'm developing my operating system in x86-64. I want to disable and enable paging(clear and set the bit 31 of CR0). But my code causes the system reset(maybe a triple fault).
The code just like this:
; Disable paging
mov rax, cr0
and rax, ~0x80000000
mov cr0, rax

; Enable paging
mov rax, cr0
or rax, 0x80000000
mov cr0, rax

NASM warns:

warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]
warning: dword data exceeds bounds [-w+number-overflow]

It seems NASM treat imm64 as imm32. I'm not sure if and r64, imm64 is a valid instruction in x86-64.

I must admit I think your triple fault may be because of another issue. NASM will generate those warnings and actually emit them as and eax,0x7fffffff and or eax,0x80000000 which should still work.

and r64, imm64 doesn't exist (see https://felixcloutier.com/x86/and) The warnings are because your immediate values are imm32 and would be sign extended into the upper half of RAX if used (not what you want). You could use btr  eax, 31 to clear the paging bit and bts eax, 31 to set the paging bit.

You don't show all your code but if you are in long mode and you wish to disable paging you will have to load 32-bit compatibility mode selectors into the segment registers including CS before disabling paging.
